# How to Resolve ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol with Docker

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle12c

Good afternoon, I am trying to run an oracle database with docker, but when I try to connect from the sql developer I get the following error:

[image]

ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

The question is that I am using the parameters that are specified to be necessary to connect to the database, such as the host ip (10.164.7.203) and port 1521:

[image]

Try to apply the solution described here:

https://logic.edchen.org/how-to-resolve-ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol/

[image: **enter image description here**]

but I haven't managed to solve the problem either

The container is lifting normally and I have even done operations with sqlplus and everything is fine

[image]

Comment: What is your jdbc driver version? For `12.2` you need `ojdbc8.jar` or higher. See [What are the Oracle JDBC releases Vs JDK versions?](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html)

Comment: How do I verify and install this inside a container?

Comment: What is the version of your `SQL Developer`? Maybe you need simple upgrade it. The JDBC Driver is integrated in the SQL Developer.

Comment: I managed to resolve by updating the version of SQL Developer.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

the container DON'T use `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.ora`

you must modify in

```
/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin/ORCLCDB
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8
```